# How can I populate my highchart using Ajax.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I want to use the ajax call commented out below to import the data from an external file (all-client-job-data-extended.js) instead of having the data above.  How can I do this? I am really struggling.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

 
 var json=
 [
   {
   "Hot": false,
   "Country": "NETHERLANDS",
   "DomCountry": "NA",
   "DomPortCode": "*PI",
   "Code": "RTM",
   "Origin": "NL",
   "CodeDest": "NA",
   },
   {
   "Hot": true,
   "Country": "GREAT BRITAIN",
   "DomCountry": "POLAND",
   "DomPortCode": "*PI",
   "Code": "CAL",
   "Origin": "GB",
   "CodeDest": "PL",
   },
   {
   "Hot": true,
   "Country": "GREAT BRITAIN",
   "DomCountry": "POLAND",
   "DomPortCode": "*PI",
   "Code": "CAL",
   "Origin": "GB",
   "CodeDest": "PL",
   }
 ];
 
  
  var countryCounts = {};
  var countryNames  = [];
  var totalCount    = 0;

  
  /*  I want to use this Ajax call to import the data from an external file (all-client-job-data-extended.js) instead of having it above.  How can I do this? I am really struggling. 

  $.ajax({
   url: "all-client-job-data-extended.js", 
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(r){
    window.json = r;
   }
  });
  */
 
 
  //loop through the object
  $.each(json, function(i, node) {
   
   //get the country name
   var countryName = node["Country"];
   
   //build array of unique country names
   if($.inArray(countryName, countryNames) == -1) {
      countryNames.push(countryName);
   }
      
   //add or increment a count for the country name
   if(typeof countryCounts[countryName] == 'undefined') {
    countryCounts[countryName] = 1;
   }
   else {
    countryCounts[countryName]++;
   }
   
   //increment the total count so we can calculate %
   totalCount++;
  });
 
  //console.log(countryNames);

  var data = [];

  //loop through unique countries to build data for chart
  $.each(countryNames, function(i, countryName) {
   data.push({
    name: countryName,
    y: Math.round((countryCounts[countryName] / totalCount) * 100)
   });
  });
  //console.log(data);

  // chart stuff ------------------------------------
  var chart;
  var type    = 'bar';
  var titleText    = 'Test Chart Title';
  var subTitleText = 'Test Chart Subtitle';

  $(function() {
   $('#container').highcharts({
    chart       : { type    : type          },
    title       : { text    : titleText     },
    subtitle    : {  text   : subTitleText  },
    legend      : { enabled : false          },
    tooltip     : {
     shared   : true,
     crosshairs : true
    },
    plotOptions : {
     series   : {
     }
    },
    xAxis      : { 
     categories: [],
     title  : { text: null },
     labels : { style : { fontWeight: 'bold' }
     }
    },
    yAxis      : { 
     title  : { text: null },
     labels : { 
      formatter: function() {
       return this.isLast ? this.value + '%' : this.value;
      }
     }
    }
   }); 
   chart = $('#container').highcharts();
   chart.addSeries({ data: data });
   
   
  })
 
});
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  <title>Highchart</title>
 </head>
<body>
 <h1>Highchart</h1>
  
 <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See example [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/getting-data-across-domains-jsonp) - as you can see chart is created **inside** AJAX callback. AJAX by default is async, so assigning to the global variable isn't the best idea - the rest of code will be executed **before** data from backend will arrive.

Comment: This wouldn’t work as Google Chrome won’t allow loading of local files. IE does but it’s not so great. The following console error advises as such in Chrome:

Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: Ok, I'm lost :) You want to load local file by AJAX? CORS won't allow you, as you noticed.

Comment: me to ..... all I want to do is populate my chart with the data from a another file. This file will contain what is in (var json) as shown above. I want to do this because there will be allot more data in there over time and dont want it all in the same place.

Comment: But for AJAX - setup some webserver (e.g. nginx, WAMP/MAMP). Or consider different solution (if you really need to server app from localhost..) - just create `my-data.js` file, and put there **all** data like this: ` var json = ...`. Then load file by `<script/>` tag, not AJAX.

Comment: I tried ( var json = .... Then load file by <script/>` tag, ) but i didn't work. Could you sent me a quick fiddle just to see if I did it right?

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:

- `data.js` file will contain:

```
var json = [
      {
        "Hot": false,
        "Country": "NETHERLANDS",
        "DomCountry": "NA",
        "DomPortCode": "*PI",
        "Code": "RTM",
        "Origin": "NL",
        "CodeDest": "NA",
     },
     {
        "Hot": true,
        "Country": "GREAT BRITAIN",
        "DomCountry": "POLAND",
        "DomPortCode": "*PI",
        "Code": "CAL",
        "Origin": "GB",
        "CodeDest": "PL",
     },
     {
        "Hot": true,
        "Country": "GREAT BRITAIN",
        "DomCountry": "POLAND",
        "DomPortCode": "*PI",
        "Code": "CAL",
        "Origin": "GB",
        "CodeDest": "PL",
    }
];
```

- loading example (HTML):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="data.js"></script> <!-- make sure your path is proper here! -->
    <title>Highchart</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Highchart</h1>

    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Now variable `json` exists in your JS namespace.

Comment: Open to example of this working for my script. http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/getting-data-across-domains-jsonp